# How to install system-wide nuget packages?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, nuget, swig

How can I install a nuget package system-wide on visual studio 2015?

I mean, yeah, you can install nuget packages per-project and per-solution... but, is it possible to install them system-wide so they'll be available for sources using vs2015 compiler?

Right now I'm coding some swig c++ modules to be used on python with cmake and having these libraries available system-wide so I can include them like any other system header would be quite convenient.

Just to clarify, the generated project by cmake will be ninja(using vs compiler)+ST (no package manager involved)... but still I'd like to be able of using the goodies provided by nuget to have my library set ready to be used by the swig modules

Comment: There is no global install mode for NuGet. (But packages downloads are cached: using in multiple solutions will not require fresh downloads.)

Comment: It already works that way, packages are cached in %userprofile%/.nuget.  So the next time you need one in a project, it will be instantly available when you ask the package manager to add it to your project.  Doing it any other way makes no sense.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, the thing is, I'm using CMake and the generated project will be ninja(vs compiler)+ST (no package manager involved)... but still I'd like to be able of using the goodies provided by nuget to have my library set ready to be used by my swig modules

Comment: Well, nice job putting that in a comment instead of the question.  Feature requests for CMake [belong here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues).

Comment: @HansPassant Edited my question to clarify further about it. In any case, in my previous question version i was already mentioning the fact of using cmake (that didn't imply using explicitely vs project). The fact I had tagged with vs2015 is so people knew my nuget version, no idea why the negative vote. And this is not a cmake issue, is a question about using nuget to install system-wide packages, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuget package management system does not have a "system-wide" install mode.

Downloaded packages are cached, so that you are not forced to re-download them each time for each project/solution referencing them.

You can also specify a path where to put the packages, but as far as I know for C++ projects this has some drawbacks, including the fact that project files are injected with *.props file paths relative to the solution, that causes Nuget system to be hardly usable from same projects included in different solutions at different path levels.

It seems that Microsoft is moving toward a different package manager for C++ native projects, you may want to look at [VCPKG on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg).

Comment: VCPKG looks exactly what i was looking for, thanks! Although my first trial isn't going very well, after installing vcpkg and installing `sdl2:x86-windows` the library won't be found by my cmake project. And even worst, when I create a new empty win32 console application on VS and and using this [empty code](https://bpaste.net/show/dda3a1ac97d9) to prove the solution will find that library it fails miserably with this [error](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21334722/Uploads/2017/02/devenv_2017-02-22_16-10-39.png), any clue? +1 For the time being

Comment: Sincerely, I don't use VCPKG myself, I was pi**ed off by the NuGet issues, and by the fact that once more Microsoft made its own solution instead of contributing to some good C++ package managers already (widely?) used, i.e. https://www.conan.io/ or https://github.com/ruslo/hunter

Comment: I see, let me mark this then as accepted then, it basically answers my main question, this one would be an additional one, which is troubleshooting about vcpkg. I've opened a new one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395981/get-up-and-running-vcpkg) in case anyone is interested on it. Anyway, thanks by mentioning vcpkg... it looks really promising ;-D

Comment: How this relates to "globalPackagesFolder" ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders